# How to authenticate FB Workplace Account Management API in PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, curl, facebook-workplace

How to authenticate FB Workplace Account Management API in PHP?

They haven't given much detail in the documentation but still here is the link for the documentation.(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/authentication/password)

And here is the code that I have written to get authentication so that I can get the list of users.Though I want to later add and delete them also and it can be done only through Account Management API and not the graph API.

Code:

```
$username='adnan@outsourcewebdev.com';

$password='P3YPFTluXc18'; 

//Its a trial acc username & pass. You can use to test it.

$URL='https://work-48884897.facebook.com/work/login';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

$result=curl_exec ($ch);

print_r($result); 

$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  

echo $status_code; //get status code

curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Account Management API, like the other Facebook APIs, requires an access token, not a username/password combination.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/account-management/api

> The Workplace Account Management API will only process requests that include a valid access token, which you must send with your API invocations as an authorization header.

The docs you're referencing just explain that users can authenticate to the Facebook *website* in more than one way - either via username/password *or* an SSO.